# Connection to cosmos db using microsoft azure documentdb api results in bad request error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to connect to cosmosDb using azure-documentdb api. 
[image]
The code snippet I am attaching is w.r.t. the screenshot added above.

public class CosmosDBConnection {

```
private static final String HOST = "my-key";
private static final String MASTER_KEY = "master-key";
private static final String DATABASE_ID = "TablesDB";
private static DocumentClient documentClient = new 
DocumentClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY,
        ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault(), ConsistencyLevel.Session);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DocumentClient documentClient = getDocumentClient();
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM root r r.id='" + DATABASE_ID+ "'";
        FeedResponse feedResponse = documentClient.queryDatabases(queryString, null);
        if(feedResponse != null){
            List<Database> databaseList = feedResponse.getQueryIterable().toList();
            System.out.println("At 19 line");
            Database databaseCache = new Database();
            if (databaseList.size() > 0) {
                databaseCache = databaseList.get(0);
            } else {

                Database databaseDefinition = new Database();
                databaseDefinition.setId(DATABASE_ID);
                databaseCache = documentClient.createDatabase(databaseDefinition, null).getResource();

            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("feedResponse is null");
        }

    } catch (DocumentClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static DocumentClient getDocumentClient() {
    return documentClient;
}
```

}

The line resulting in error is -> documentClient.queryDatabases(queryString, null);

Comment: I have also tried with DATABASE_ID = "order_details" and it was resulting into the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That screenshot is from a Table API account. You are using the SQL API SDK.

If you want to use a Table API account, you would need to use the [Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table) SDK (for .NET, there are [SDKs for other languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction#next-steps)). In that SDK, you can create tables like so:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient(new TableClientConfiguration());

CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("order_details");
if (await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Created Table named: order_details");
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("Table order_details already exists");
}
```

If you don't need to work with the Tables API, you can create a SQL API account and use the code you already have.

Extracting the body of the BadRequest response will probably show you the reason for that request to have failed, which might point to the fact that you are mixing the SQL API SDK with a Tables API account.

Comment: Thanks @Matias for replying!! Is the DATABASE_ID = "TablesDB" correct or it should be "order_details" with reference to the screenshot attached.

Comment: According to the screenshot, the name of the database is TablesDB, and collection name is order_details.